# How I can get available timezones (android:settings)

Tags: android, timezone, settings

I want to get **TimeZones**, that I can see in settings: **Date and Time** -->

[image: Select time zone]

Yes, I know, that in java/android can get all timezones by `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`, but I want get only timezones, that exists on

[image: settings screen].

Comment: Date & Time settings screen contains two fields first Zone Names and second related time for Zone then which field you want ?

Comment: means you wanna get current timezone????

Comment: @altaf, no I want get all timezone ids, that you can see in settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I already try to select one offset - one timezone. But in this case get another error. I used this timezone on programmatically add event to google calendar (parse ics-file). With some timezone I have issue. For example, I add event with timezone +6 GMT.

getAvailableIDs() return with this offset some first timezone (I do not exactly remember, but timezone was ".../Vostok"). If I try add event with this timezone, then I opened this added event in Google Calendar android application and see, that timezone set not as normal "America/New York" or "Europe/Moscow", but simply "+ 6 GMT".

So I began to look list "standart" timezones. Now I used some another way. I search in google calendar [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git) and find that they do not get timezone in runtime with some proc, but simply set some timezone ids in static array. Now I also used this list. I do not know, how this list changed from android version. But worked correct on 4.x and 2.x

Comment: I think there is no method to get only timezones that are listed in settings: Date & time -> Select time zone

Answer (score 12):

As you noticed, it is possible to get a list of all the `TimeZone`s available on your device by invoking `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`, however, this usually returns you a list of 500+ `TimeZone`s with a `displayName` that's not always user friendly (like a `GMT+05:00`).

So now, if you take a look at Android's timezones list, it is only comprised of about 80 elements, with nicely formatted names and all.
By looking at the source code (up to Kitkat), you can see that they actually retrieve their timezones from a xml located in [`/res/xml/timezones.xml`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/kitkat-release/res/xml/timezones.xml).
Each row is defined like follow:

`<timezone id="America/New_York">Eastern Time</timezone>`

So what they do, is parse the whole `timezones.xml` file and [put the (Olson) `id` and `text` in a List of Timezone `Map`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/datetime/ZonePicker.java).

```
public static SimpleAdapter constructTimezoneAdapter(Context context,
            boolean sortedByName, int layoutId) {
        final String[] from = new String[] {ZoneGetter.KEY_DISPLAYNAME, ZoneGetter.KEY_GMT};
        final int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

        final String sortKey = (sortedByName ? ZoneGetter.KEY_DISPLAYNAME : ZoneGetter.KEY_OFFSET);
        final MyComparator comparator = new MyComparator(sortKey);
        final List<Map<String, Object>> sortedList = ZoneGetter.getZonesList(context);
        Collections.sort(sortedList, comparator);
        final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context,
                sortedList,
                layoutId,
                from,
                to);

        return adapter;
    }
```

Next, for each Timezone `Map` in that List, they retrieve the associated `TimeZone` thanks to `TimeZone.getTimeZone(String id)` and add the associated `offset` and `GMT` to it.

So in the end, what they display really, is a list of timezones where they retrieve the IDs from a file: `timezones.xml`.

---

Something that could work if you have one id per timezone, is to just make up a list of Olson ids and show their `displayName`.
That might not work if you have more since some Olson ids hold the same `displayName` as other ones, like: `Europe/Amsterdam` and `Europe/Brussels` both refer to `European Central Time`.

Note: This post is mostly focused on Kit Kat and might not apply to lower/higher version. If you wish to get more info for your own version, please refer to: [this link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+refs)

Comment: In case that someone is looking for an updated version of timezones.xml (in this case android 9), the file's location has changed: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-9.0.0_r33/packages/SettingsLib/res/xml/timezones.xml

Answer (score 5):

```
String[]TZ = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
        ArrayList<String> TZ1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < TZ.length; i++) {
            if(!(TZ1.contains(TimeZone.getTimeZone(TZ[i]).getDisplayName()))) {
                TZ1.add(TimeZone.getTimeZone(TZ[i]).getDisplayName());
            }
        }
```

> I think this one is help you

Answer (score 0):

Once you've called `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();`, you can use [`TimeZone.getTimeZone(id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone%28java.lang.String%29) to get a [`TimeZone`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html) object. With this object, you can get the name (using [`.getDisplayName()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDisplayName%28%29)), or the offset (using [`.getRawOffset()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getRawOffset%28%29), which returns the millisecond offset).

```
String[] timezones = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
for (String tzId : timezones) {
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(tzId);
    String name = tz.getDisplayName();
    int offset = tz.getRawOffset();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Guys, I need ids, from which I can get name/offset.
@Eric, TimeZone.getAvailableIDs() for my android return more, than 500 items. For example, for GMT-11:00 it return 5 items...

Comment: Then keep a list of the `offset`s that you've already returned, and don't use that one a second time. Trust me--this is where Android's time zone preferences screen comes from. ;)

Comment: I use a Set<String> add all timezone Ids to filter out those have same id. And getTimezone with element of this Set. Works fine for me.