# How I can get available timezones (android:date and time settings)

Tags: android, timezone

I want to get TimeZones, that I can see in settings: Date and Time 
Yes, I know, that in java/android can get all timezones by `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(),`
 but I want get only timezones, that exists on settings: Date and Time

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14062173/1979882 . In brief,  I do not think that there is method your are looking for.

Comment: By the way, in Java [`ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#getAvailableZoneIds()) replaced `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs` as of Java 8 and later.